# Getting id of channel that message was sent in

Tags: python, discord.py

What i want to do is find the channel the message was sent in.

Ex:

`async def on_message(on_message):
  # Get Channel Id
  channel bot.get_channel(channel_id)
  await channel.send('test')`

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message). You should instead name the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) object that `on_message` is being passed something like `message`.

That `Message` object has a [`channel` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel) that is the [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) the message was sent in.
That `TextChannel` object also has an [`id` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.id) that is the channel's ID.

For help with markdown, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.